# javascript retrieve value from a map

Tags: javascript, dictionary, google-apps-script

I am trying to develop a google script app.

Here is one function to create an array map.

```
function getOffices(){
 var result=AdminDirectory.Groups.list({domain:"example.com"})
  result=result.groups.filter(function(group){
    var str=group.email;
     return str.search("-office@example.com")>=0;
  })
  result=result.map(function(group){ return {name:group.name,email:group.email}})
 
  return result;
}
```

I have created a logic piece, that I want to execute certain actions based on the results, that looks like this:

```
var getOrgUnitPath = (accountOffice, accountType) => {
if (accountType === 'facilitator') {
  return 'Limited Accounts/Gmail Plus Calendar';
} else {
  switch (accountOffice) {
    case accountOffice.includes('Boston'):
      return "/Standard-Access/Boston";
      break;
    case accountOffice.includes('New York'):
      return '/Standard-Access/New York';
      break;
    case accountOffice.includes('Lincoln'):
      return '/Standard-Access/Lincoln';
      break;
    default:
      return '/Standard-Access';
      break;
  }
}
```

};

Lastly, I try to set the organizational unit -- which is ultimately what i am trying to do, but can't seem to get the syntax right, I have tried everything I can think of. I have hardcoded the "accountType" and it worked, so I know the formObject.accountType is functioning properly.

```
orgUnitPath: getOrgUnitPath(accountType, formObject.accountType),
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the script? What is the end goal?

Answer (score 0):

This is a wrong usage of switch case.

if `accountOffice`'s would be just New York, Boston, Lincoln. Remove the complex condition and replace with

```js
switch (accountOffice) {
  case "Boston":
    return "/Standard-Access/Boston";
    break;
  case "New York":
    return "/Standard-Access/New York";
    break;
  case "Lincoln":
    return "/Standard-Access/Lincoln";
    break;
  default:
    return "/Standard-Access";
    break;
}
```

If not, use if-else if you have complex condition to check rather than simple match cases

```js
if (accountOffice.includes("Boston")) {
  return "/Standard-Access/Boston";
} else if (accountOffice.includes("New York")) {
  return "/Standard-Access/New York";
} else if (accountOffice.includes("Lincoln")) {
  return "/Standard-Access/Lincoln";
} else {
  return "/Standard-Access";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote the code so I could get a better understanding of it. From what I can tell, `getOffices` lists all offices and `getOrgUnitPath` returns a path including the first office that matches the ordered list of offices `['Boston', 'NY', 'Lincoln']`. If that's the case, what's missing is that the first argument to `getOrgUnitPath` should be `getOffices()`, right? (Notice it is the execution of the function `getOffices`.)

Here's the code "simplified" to my liking. I hope it helps:

```
const getOffices = () => {
  const bigList = x.y.list({ domain: 'example.com' }) // ?
  return bigList
    .filter(cur => ~cur.email.search('abc'))
    .map(cur => ({
      name: cur.name,
      email: cur.email
    }))
}

const getPath = (accOffice, accType) => {
  if (accType === 'xyz')
    return 'foobar'
  const city = ['Boston', 'NY', 'Lincoln']
    .find(cur => accOffice.includes(cur))
  return `yadayada/${city}`
}

const theFinalObj = {
  orgUnitPath: getPath(getOffices(), 'rightHardcodedType')
}
```